# $a^{th}$-root of exponential generating functions

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, generating-functions

This is a quick follow up on [R. Stanley's interesting post on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385303/the-square-root-of-a-graph) in a different direction, which might be easier.

For positive integers $a$, define the family of functions (infinite series) given by
$$F_a(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}a^{\binom{n+1}2}\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
Then, $F_2(x)$ becomes Stanley's $F(x)$.

> **QUESTION.** Is it true that the coefficients of $\sqrt[a]{F_a(x)}$ are all positive integers, as an exponential generating function?

Comment: In fact, we can let $a$ be an indeterminate, and the coefficient of $x^n/n!$ in $\sqrt[a]{F_a(x)}$ will be a polynomial with integer coefficients. This is because $a^{{n+1\choose 2}}$ counts graphs with edges colored with $a$ colors (including the color 0, which denotes no edge). Thus the number $c_a(n)$ of connected such graphs on $n\geq 1$ vertices is a polynomial in $a$ with integer coefficients and is divisible by $a$. Thus the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ in $\exp \frac{1}{a}c_a(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sqrt[a]{F_a(x)}$ is a polynomial in $a$ with integer coefficients.

Comment: @RichardStanley: It would be nice if you could put this as an answer so that your cute argument won't be buried here. It is instructional to readers.

Comment: I have done as you suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, we can let $a$ be an indeterminate, and the coefficient of $x^n/n!$ in $\sqrt[a]{F_a(x)}$ will be a polynomial with integer coefficients. This is because $a^{{n+1\choose 2}}$ counts graphs with edges colored with $a$ colors (including the color 0, which denotes no edge). Thus the number $c_a(n)$ of connected such graphs on $n≥1$ vertices is a polynomial in $a$ with integer coefficients and is divisible by $a$. Hence the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ in $\exp \frac 1a\sum_{n\geq 1}c_a(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}$  is a polynomial in $a$ with integer coefficients.

**Addendum.** Let me explain why $c_a(n)$ is divisible by $a$. Let
$G$ be a connected graph on $n$ vertices with no loops. If $G$ has
$q$ edges, then there are $(a-1)^q$ ways to color them. (The
nonedges, corresponding to the color 0, are already determined by
$G$.) At each vertex we are free to add a loop or not without
affecting connectedness. If we add a loop, we can color it in
$a-1$ ways, so $a$ possibilities in all for each vertex. Hence the
total number of coloring of all graphs obtained from $G$ by adding
loops is $(a-1)^q a^n$.  This is divisible by $a$ (since $n\geq 1$),
and summing over all $G$ without loops will therefore give a
polynomial divisible by $a$, as claimed.

Now note that if $n\geq 2$, then $q\geq 1$ so $(a-1)^q a^n$ is
divisible by $a^2(a-1)$. Hence
$$ \exp \frac 1a\sum_{n\geq 1}c_a(n)\frac{x^n}{n!} =
  \exp\left( x+\sum_{n\geq 2}a(a-1)d_a(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}\right), $$
for some $d_a(n)\in\mathbb{Z}[a]$. Taking this modulo $a(a-1)$ gives
$e^x=\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{x^m}{m!}$. It follows that the conjecture
in OEIS A178319 mentioned in the comment by Max Alekseyev is true.

Comment: There is a conjecture in [OEIS A178319](https://oeis.org/A178319) that the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ in $\exp \frac 1a\sum_{n\geq 1}c_a(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $a(a-1)$ for all $n\geq 0$. Can it be seen from the given interpretation?

Comment: You can get $(a-1)^q a^n$ more easily by starting with the $(a-1)^q$ colorings without loops and then at each of the $n$ vertices adding a loop in any of the $a$ colors, where color $0$ corresponds to no loop.

Comment: @IraGessel: yes, I also realized this after posting my answer. I have revised the text accordingly.